# Hats Displayed On Questions Lose Position If Collapsed Comments Are Expanded

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

Is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721837/how-can-i-remove-domain-name-from-a-directory-file-uri) you can see the hat is on the user icon correctly, but there are collapsed comments.

[image]

---

Clicking *"show 2 more comments"* to expand the comments will show the comments, but since the page positions change the hat is still in the original location even though the content has shifted down.

[image]

Comment: Reproduced in safari 7.0.1

Comment: `status-repro` on Chrome 31.0.1650.48.

Comment: No repro here on Chrome 31.0.1650.63.

Comment: @3ventic I can repro it on 31.0.1650.63

Comment: It's because it's a non-square avatar. Those always cause problems :\ Works fine for the majority. Fixing...

Comment: I can repro on IE11, and I think the difference is that I cannot see his avatar on Chrome at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in a comment, that user has one of the rare non-square avatars, and that case wasn't handled correctly. Fixed now.