# Top-bar hat misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, winter-bash-2013

In my profile my hat is on the correct position, but not in the top-bar. This is new. It worked until now.

[image: profile]

Works neither in Chrome nor in Firefox.

Comment: Perhaps it was related to the change made from this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213089/hats-displayed-on-questions-lose-position-if-collapsed-comments-are-expanded (not a duplicate, just related). Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211745/178816

Comment: Reproed here, hat goes too much to the right.

Comment: Yup, started seeing this on December 21.

Comment: Interesting thing for me is that it only happens on SO; it's fine here.

Comment: [status-reproduced] here on all SE sites.

Comment: Seems, I am hitting this as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213140/hats-inconistent-rendering

Comment: My hat is still askance (Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m, Win7 x64): http://imgur.com/hJ3mAsU

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As was already suspected in the comments, the fix for [Hats Displayed On Questions Lose Position If Collapsed Comments Are Expanded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213089/hats-displayed-on-questions-lose-position-if-collapsed-comments-are-expanded) broke this; it was somewhat half-baked and opend up other edge cases. Fixed correctly this time, including the top bar hat.

Comment: Can't believe we survived for long hours with such a bug! ;)

Comment: @balpha: yeah, confirmed. Thanks a lot.