# Hats: Inconsistent rendering

Tags: discussion, support, bug, winter-bash-2013

It looks a bit silly question and not that important question, so it is just out of curiosity. Please bear with me. :)

I have just noticed it this morning that the hat is rendered differently on the avatar between the profile page and the one in the top bar on the left of the reputation count and the badges.

I wonder if it is a bug or whether I am doing something wrong. You can find the screenshots taken below. The difference seems to be appealing for instance at my left eye.

[image][image: enter image description heres]

Comment: [meta-tag:winderbash-2012]?

Comment: Oh, indeed, it is the dup of that. Flexo, that was the recommended tag. Looks like a bug to report separately. ;-)